# Batman 1966 - The Joker is Wild - who are the actors behind the busts?

Tags: dc, batman, the-joker

In the episode the Joker is Wild, the Joker is in a museum and four henchmen come out from behind the busts of four famous comedians.  I was wondering if anyone knew the four actors that appear next to the busts of the four comedians. Two are pretty easy. Gil Perkins is Oliver Hardy and Roger Creed is W.C. Fields. I cannot figure out Stan Laurel and Ernie Kovacs.

Answer (score 3):

IMDB shows [Pete Kellett](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0445853/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t14), [Gil Perkins](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0673945/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t16), and [Al Wyatt Sr.](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0943511/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t20) as "uncredited" henchmen in the cast. If indeed Roger Creed was in there as well, that would account for all four.

[This site](http://www.aveleyman.com/TVEpisode.aspx?FilmID=31&Episode=19660126) claims:

> Gil Perkins
>
> [image: Gil Perkins]

.

> Al Wyatt Sr
>
> [image: Al Wyatt Sr]

Comment: Al Wyatt Sr was a henchman in the episode after the scene with the henchmen coming from behind the busts.  The original henchmen must have been captured by Batman and Robin because those four did not appear in the episode again.

Comment: @CalvinWBoaz: Huh. In that case, I'm baffled. I don't have access to the actual episode, so I can't do much cross-checking there.

Comment: Pete Kellett was the actor that came from behind the bust of Ernie Kovacs.  That leaves the actor behind Stan Laurel.

Comment: In this photo, Gil Perkins is on the left.  It is the henchman on the right I am trying to identify. https://goo.gl/images/3fQokG